# Tensorflow.js loading model returns function predict is not defined

Tags: javascript, tensorflow.js

When I load a saved model like this (please dont mind the fact that the predict function has no input)

```
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs');
require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');

const model = tf.loadModel('file://./model-1a/model.json').then(() => {
  model.predict();
});
```

I get this error:

> (node:25887) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError:
>   model.predict is not a function
>       at tf.loadModel.then (/home/ubuntu/workspace/server.js:10:9)
>       at

But when I just create a model instead of loading it works just fine

```
const model = tf.sequential();
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 10, inputShape: [10005]}));
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1, activation: 'linear'}));
model.compile({loss: 'meanSquaredError', optimizer: 'sgd'});
```

The model predict function works just fine? I don't know what could be wrong here and I was hopeing someone could help me out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to work with [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

`loadModel()` returns a promise resolving into the loaded model. So to access it you either need to use the `.then()` notation or be inside an `async` function and `await` it.

`.then()`:

```
tf.loadModel('file://./model-1a/model.json').then(model => {
  model.predict();
});
```

`async/await`:

```
async function processModel(){
    const model = await tf.loadModel('file://./model-1a/model.json');
    model.predict();
}
processModel();
```

or in a shorter, more direct way:

```
(async ()=>{
    const model = await tf.loadModel('file://./model-1a/model.json');
    model.predict();
})()
```

Comment: Thank you, it appears the problem in my case was that I did not pass in model as a parameter.

Comment: I want to load the model once and keep it in memory for an interactive page where multiple prediction calls are made. How do I do that?