# How to load a tensorflow.js model in a react web app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, async-await, tensorflow.js

I am working on a React web app (in Typescript) in which I want to load a tensorflow.js model and then apply it each time after the component updates. I have been able to load and apply my model in a small demo app without React, but now encounter some problems with the async load function:

My idea was to load the model in the constructor of the component, but an async function cannot be used in a constructor. So I tried to make a sort of wrapper function:

```
export default class MyGreatComponent extends React.Component<{pixels}> {
  model;
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.model = this.loadmodel('http://localhost:3333/model.json');
  }

  async loadmodel(p: any) {
    try {
      const model = await tf.loadModel(p);
      return model;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error while loading model: ");
      console.log(error);
      return error;
    }
  }
...
}
```

And then, when the component updates and I want to apply the model:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
      ... // get data etc
      const t4d = tf.tensor4d(imgarray_n, [1, width, height, 3]);
      var prediction : any = this.model.predict(t4d);
  }
```

However, this gives:

> TypeError: this.model.predict is not a function.

So I also tried a wrapper function that uses a promise (as I saw in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52545000/tensorflow-js-loading-model-returns-function-predict-is-not-defined)):

```
loadmodel(p: any){
    tf.loadModel(p).then(model => {
      return model;
    });
  }
```

But the promise seems to never resolve and gives me:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'predict' of undefined

I am not sure about what I am doing wrong, or what it is that I do not understand. I hope you guys can point out what's going wrong here. Thnx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out how silly my wrapper idea was and now load the model not in the constructor but in ComponentDidMount and that did the trick!

```
async componentDidMount() {
    this.model = await tf.loadModel('http://localhost:3333/model.json');
  }
```

Comment: any specific reason why you made it async ? -> update: because we want to use `await` doh. JS newbie, sorry